# How many types of Loops does C++ have?

Tags: c++, loops

I was told that C++ basically has three kinds of loops:

1. **for** loop
2. **while** loop
3. **do-while** loop

What about the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Isn't [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) a looping statement as well?

I'm confused what to answer if somebody asks me the number of types of Loops in C++. I understand that `for_each` is an STL algorithm which could have been implemented using one of those above looping constructs in C++. But by this logic, any of those basic loops could be simulated by one of the other loops.

Is there any quote in the C++ Standard which confirms the number?

Comment: STL algorithms are not part of the C++ language itself, they are framework implementations, so I wouldn't include them in the list. Like you said, they are built on top of the language-provided loops. A Range-based `for` loop is part of the language, though, so add that to the list. You might consider also adding `goto` to the list, too. Although it is not strictly a loop, it can be used to create a loop.

Comment: You forgot recursion and `goto`. Anyway, the question isn’t answered by the standard because there is no reason to mention this: it’s purely a debate of terms, and not interesting in itself.

Comment: For completeness; `setjmp` / `longjmp` can also be used to implement loops (but please don't).

Comment: `for_each` is a function (template), not a statement, and not part of the language itself. If you call that a loop, you can call any function a loop.

Comment: I would say that @Ardent has already listed the loops available in standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What about the range-based for loop?

A range based `for` loop is a loop.

> Isn't for_each a looping statement as well?

No, it's a function template.

> I'm confused what to answer if somebody asks me the number of types of Loops in C++

Depends on what they mean. One may include `goto` and recursion in addition to `for`, `while`, `do while` but not the STL algorithms, others may include everything that is capable of repeating a piece of code, yet others may just count `goto` as the "real deal" because other loops can be emulated with `goto`. Then there is also `setjmp`/`longjmp`. In any case that is a vague and unuseful question.

Comment: Well, you could give them the reasoning in this answer. I'm sure they can't disagree.

Comment: There's also `setjmp`/`longjmp`.